# Get content from another DB in wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have found out how to make a page for WordPress, where I can write PHP code into.
However, I can not figure out how to retrieve content from another database.
I have found the connect code:

```
$wpdb2 = new wpdb($dbname, $dbpass, $dbuname, $dbhost);
```

but I cannot figure out how to retrieve content from the database.
Can someone give an example?
If, for example, have this query

```
SELECT number
FROM qr_statistic
WHERE date = '$today'
```

Answer (score 1):

please see this:

```
wpdb::get_results( string $query = null, string $output = OBJECT )
```

now you can write your query:

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT number FROM $wpdb->qr_statistic WHERE WHERE date = '$today'");
```

also see [this link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/110677/get-results-using-wpdb)